# Snowflake task failure notification

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have Snowflake tasks that runs every 30 minutes. Currently, when the task fails due to underlying data issue in the stored procedure that the Task calls, there is no way to notify the users on the failure.

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE(INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TASK_HISTORY());
```

How can notifications be setup for a Snowflake Task failure? The design plan I have in mind is to build a python application that runs every 30mins and looks for any error on TASK_HISTORY table. Please advise if there are any better approaches to handle failure notifications

Answer (score 4):

I think currently a python script would the best way to address this.
You can use this SQL to query last runs, read into a data frame and filter out errors

```
select *
  from table(information_schema.task_history(scheduled_time_range_start=>dateadd(minutes, -30,current_timestamp())))
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I would want to create an HPSM ticket so that a ticket and alert could be created and sent to the team. How can I incorporate that here?

Comment: I am not familiar with HPSM ticketing system

Comment: Instead of writing python script , you can create one more task to run every 30 mins to  pull output data from task history and pull out errors.

Comment: Thanks, Anand. Eventually, I would want to create HPSM ticket for the failures. I was looking if there are any ways to create HPSM tickets through Python. Not sure if Snowflake has that feature.

Comment: At this point, there is no OOTB mechanism for Task failure notification but this is a feature that will be available in due course of time. Though it cannot create HPSM tickets the notifications could be customized.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to create Notification Integration and send message when error occurs. As of May 2022 this feature is in preview, supported by accounts on Amazon Web Servives.

##### [Enabling Error Notifications for Tasks](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/tasks-errors.html#enabling-error-notifications-for-tasks)

> This topic provides instructions for configuring error notification support for tasks using cloud messaging. **This feature triggers a notification describing the errors encountered when a task executes SQL code**
>
> ```
> Currently, error notifications rely on cloud messaging provided by the
> Amazon Simple Notification Service service;
> support for Google Cloud Pub/Sub queue and Microsoft Azure Event Grid is planned.
> ```
>
> New Tasks
>
> Create a new task using CREATE TASK. For descriptions of all available task parameters, see the SQL command topic:
>
> ```
> CREATE TASK <name>
>  [...]
>  ERROR_INTEGRATION = <integration_name>
>  AS <sql>
> ```
>
> Existing tasks:
>
> ```
> ALTER TASK <name> SET ERROR_INTEGRATION = <integration_name>;
> ```

Answer (score 0):

A new Snowflake feature was announced for Task Error Notifications on AWS via SNS. This doc walks though how to set this up for task failures.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/tasks-errors.html